Laravel 11 auth, email field as an aggregate of two columns
I am working on custom auth for Laravel 11 using only laravel/ui as I do not need any of the features in Breeze/Jetstream.
In my users table (custom, external service table), a users' "email address" is compromised of two fields, their userid and their realm.
On my Users model I have:
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'passwd',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @return array<string, string>
     */
    protected function casts(): array
    {
        return [
            'passwd' => 'hashed',
            'isActive' => 'boolean',
            'isPriv' => 'boolean',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the user's email address.
     */
    protected function authEmail(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn () => $this->userid . '@' . $this->realm,
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the user's active status.
     */
    protected function isActive(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn () => $this->active,
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the user's priv status.
     */
    protected function isPriv(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn () => $this->priv > 0,
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the password field for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->passwd;
    }

... authEmail is fillable.
In my LoginController:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        //$this->middleware('auth')->only('logout');
    }

    /**
     * Column name for auth.
     */
    public function username()
    {
        return 'authEmail';
    }

    /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt.
     */
    public function authenticate(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'authEmail' => ['required', 'email'],
            'passwd' => ['required'],
        ]);
 
        if (Auth::attempt([$credentials, 'isActive' => 1, 'isPriv' => 1])) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
 
            return redirect()->intended('home');
        } else {
            dd('attempt failed');
        }
 
        return back()->withErrors([
            'authEmail' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
        ])->onlyInput('authEmail');
    }
}

...the email field in the login form has been updated to authEmail.
However, despite the accessor and setting username() to authEmail, when I attempt to auth, I get:
column "authEmail" does not exist
How can I customize the email part of the authentication workflow to use my aggregate attribute instead of a single column?
Thank you.
EDIT 1:
Adjusted as indicated however I still get column "authEmail" does not exist
    public function authenticate(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'authEmail' => ['required', 'email'],
            'password' => ['required'],
        ]);

        $email = $credentials['authEmail'];
        $passwd = $credentials['password'];
        list($userid, $realm) = explode('@', $email);
 
        if (Auth::attempt([
            'userid' => $userid,
            'realm' => $realm,
            'passwd' => $passwd,
            'isActive' => 1,
            'isPriv' => 1])
            ) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
 
            return redirect()->intended('home');
        }
 
        return back()->withErrors([
            'authEmail' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
            'password' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
        ])->onlyInput('authEmail');
    }

EDIT 2: In the end, the following worked and required no accessor or password field definition on the model:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function username()
    {
        return 'userid';
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to log the user into the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $userid = $this->credentials($request)['userid'];
        $passwd = $this->credentials($request)['password'];
        list($userid, $realm) = explode('@', $userid);
    
        $user = \App\Models\RadUser::
              where('userid', $userid)
            ->where('realm', $realm)
            ->where('active', true)
            ->where('priv', '>', 0)
            ->first();
    
        if ($user && Hash::check($passwd, $user->passwd)) {
            return $this->guard('web')->login($user);
        }
        return false;
    }
}


$crediantials should be ['user_id'=>{user_id},'realm'=>{realm},'password'=>{password}] and I suggest use php->explode function to get user_id and realm from authEmail

See edit, no change, thank you

Can you add the migration file ?

@xenooooo see most recent edit, I did get it to work.
